# RCurl (with digest authentication) not setting realm correctly on Windows

Tags: r, request, httprequest, rcurl

I've been working on an R interface to a HTTP API with digest authentication and I've been running into a problem wherein the request will work absolutely fine on my non-Windows OSs, but I always get 401 status when running exactly the same code on Windows.

I'm currently trying to do it with RCurl, but the same thing was happening with httr when I tried that.

Also the API is unfotunately proprietary so I've had to change all the URLs, sorry.

On my non-Windows OSs I get the following behaviour:

```
rprompt> getURL('http://demo.someapi.net/some/url', userpwd="demo:demo", httpauth=1L, verbose=TRUE)
*   Trying 195.224.16.34...
* Connected to demo.someapi.net (195.224.16.34) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.0 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
* Server certificate: *.someapi.net
* Server certificate: RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
* Server certificate: GeoTrust Global CA
> GET /some/url HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.someapi.net
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
< WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="company.product", nonce="MTEvMDcvMjAxNiAwODo0NTozMw", opaque="0000000000000000", stale=false, algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2016 08:44:33 GMT
< Content-Length: 1293
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host demo.someapi.net left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://demo.someapi.net/some/url'
* Found bundle for host demo.someapi.net: 0x7f96c8d55af0
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host demo.someapi.net
* Connected to demo.someapi.net (195.224.16.34) port 443 (#0)
* Server auth using Digest with user 'demo'
> GET /some/url HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.someapi.net
Authorization: Digest username="demo", realm="company.product", nonce="MTEvMDcvMjAxNiAwODo0NTozMw", uri="/some/url", cnonce="YjRkMDQxYmM4MDFkYTMxOWZhNTViNGNmYTM5YzQyNGI=", nc=00000001, qop=auth, response="5d9643d083b2380f12d71855a98ceac3", opaque="0000000000000000", algorithm="MD5"
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Length: 981
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2016 08:44:33 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host demo.someapi.net left intact
```

and evertything works exactly as we expect it to. On Windows however we get this:

```
rprompt> getURL('http://demo.someapi.net/some/url', userpwd="demo:demo", httpauth=1L, verbose=TRUE)
*   Trying 195.224.16.34...
* Connected to demo.someapi.net (195.224.16.34) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: C:/Users/username/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/RCurl/etc/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.0 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: OU=GT56411961; OU=See www.rapidssl.com/resources/cps (c)15; OU=Domain Control Validated - RapidSSL(R); CN=*.someapi.net
*    start date: 2015-01-26 09:31:11 GMT
*    expire date: 2018-03-28 16:30:51 GMT
*    subjectAltName: demo.someapi.net matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=GeoTrust Inc.; CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA - G3
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /some/url HTTP/1.1
Host: demo.someapi.net
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
< WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="company.product", nonce="MTEvMDcvMjAxNiAwODo1MjowOA", opaque="0000000000000000", stale=false, algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2016 08:51:07 GMT
< Content-Length: 1293
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host demo.someapi.net left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://demo.someapi.net/some/url'
* Found bundle for host demo.someapi.net: 0xaa60b80
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host demo.someapi.net
* Connected to demo.someapi.net (195.224.16.34) port 443 (#0)
* Server auth using Digest with user 'demo'
> GET /some/url HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Digest username="demo",realm="",nonce="MTEvMDcvMjAxNiAwODo1MjowOA",uri="/some/url",cnonce="553f542ddef0e3c265e50539297bad81",nc=00000001,algorithm=MD5,response="1ec58793bb1d8142f09af112b905fa36",qop="auth",opaque="0000000000000000"
Host: demo.someapi.net
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="company.product", nonce="MTEvMDcvMjAxNiAwODo1MjowOA", opaque="0000000000000000", stale=false, algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Mon, 11 Jul 2016 08:51:07 GMT
< Content-Length: 1293
<
* Connection #0 to host demo.someapi.net left intact
```

which just returns a 401 landing page HTML.

The issue seems to be that the `realm` field is empty, but I have no idea how to fix this or even how to work around it.

It should be noted that both .NET's webclient and Python's requests library handles things fine, but unfortunately this has to be done in R.

I'm happy to use any R packages that are needed to help solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who ends up with a similar problem, you can get around it by using httr and using your own handles.

```
make.request <- function (url, user, pass) {
    handle <- httr::handle(url)
    response <- GET(url=NULL, authenticate(user, pass, type="digest"), handle=handle)
    # error checking and stuff...
}
```

I'm not sure what the issue is with RCurl though.